# Issue with getMonth() Method Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

getMonth() javascript method returns the month of the Date and values are (0-11) 0 for January and 11 for December.

If today was "2015-03-01" (first day of March 2015), getMonth() should return **2**  but instead it returns **1**. Why is this? how can I solve this issue?

Help!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Date Example</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = new Date("2015-03-01");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.getMonth();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I "Run code Snippet" It shows this:

[image: example of result]

Comment: Seeing it returns 2 in your example and also when doing this in the console `var x = new Date("2015-03-01"); x.getMonth()` What is the issue?

Comment: Even your sample code snippet here outputs "2".

Comment: Well that's funny, it returns 1 for me when I run code snippet.

Comment: Perhaps he is in a different timezone. Try
`var x = new Date(2015,2,1,12,0,0,0);` for first of march 2015

Comment: Concerning my "duplicate question". I have checked the "original question" and yes I already know that dateObject.getMonth()+1 gives you the exact month. However I believe that my question is a different issue as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: The problem is that an ISO format date string is treated as UTC, so if you're west of Greenwich, "2015-03-01" will be sometime on 28 Feb 2015, so *getMonth* returns 1. If you use *getUTCMonth*, you'll get 2. This is a duplicate of parsing, not month index.

Comment: @RobG getUTCMonth does work!! Thankyou for help!

Answer (score 0):

getMonth() method of Date always return result with zero base.So to get exact month number you should always be using .getMonth()+1 like below

```
<script>
var x = new Date("2015-03-01");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.getMonth()+1;

</script>
```

This will paint the  desired result.

Comment: Thankyou but I already know that. That is not the issue. I edited my question and I added a screenshot to ilustrate my issue. People tell me that when they run  my sample code snippet  it outputs  "2". But when I run the same code snippet it outputs "1". You can click in "example of result" in my edited question to see the screenshot.

Comment: @toreohm—this is a duplicate, but of [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) The date string is parsed as UTC, so if you're west of Greenwich the local date will be 28 Feb 2015 and *getMonth* returns 1. Try *getUTCMonth*, it will return 2.

Comment: @RobG getUTCMonth did work!! Thanks!  Since you have gave me the solution, how can I "close" this issue (question)?

Comment: @toreohm—I've marked it as a duplicate, so it's "closed". ;-)